# Inside the callback in Array.prototype.map, reference the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

`Array.prototype.map()` returns a new array. I want to reference this new array inside the callback function passed as the argument to `Array.prototype.map()`. Can I do that?

Example

```
someArray.map(function(item, idx, arr) {
    return { theCreatedArray: xyz };
});
```

What should `xyz` be?

EDIT [Context]

Why do I want this? The object I create in the callback is of a type that relies on having a reference to the array that is referencing the object. I can't refactor this requirement so easily. I would rather satisfy it.

Comment: Why? What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: *"Can I do that?"* No. The new array is returned by `map`, there is no way to access it during the process.

Comment: It helps people to provide more useful answers and guidance if you explain a little bit about the context of your question. What is it that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it with `.map()`, but you can do it with `.reduce()`:

```
someArray.reduce(function(rv, item, idx) {
  // rv is the return value, in this case your array
  rv.push({whatever: rv});
  return rv;
}, []);
```

Comment: Should `rv.push` use `{whatever: item}` rather than `rv`? This creates an infinitely-nested list (run from my chrome console).

Comment: @ssube well it's just an example; the point is that `rv` is a reference to the array. (It's not necessarily a bad thing to have a data structure with cycles anyway.)

Comment: Excellent. Array.prototype.reduce is more capable than map, but is a more conceptually difficult function. I'll use this.